# How do I send a message after a user leaves a specific thread?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I put the following code under run_discord_bot(), but it doesn't work whatsoever.

```
@client.event
async def on_thread_member_remove(member):
    thread = member.thread
    if thread.name != 'test':
        return
    else:
        await thread.send('message')
```

I set `intents.members = True` and the bot works for other commands like responding to messages etc.

What might be wrong with this function?

Comment: Could you make sure that the `thread` is not `None`? Also, try adding a `try`/`catch` to see if there's an error.